# Posted data in gridview where I was added control dynamically

Tags: asp.net, .net

I added controls (i.e. template column) dynamically in grid view and click on button (post back) then grid view populated existing data (i.e.posted data) twice separated by

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //on init recreated controls

    // if (IsPostBack)
    {
        gvFirst.DataSource = GetData("select top 10 * from Project_Master");
        gvFirst.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the markup (grid view declaration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might be using Auto-generated fields. In design view, click the smart tag on the gridview and click "edit columns." Then uncheck the checkbox that says "Auto-generate fields." I think this should fix your problem if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: @Hummpy.I have already used property "AutoGenerateColumns="false"" but my question is when I add dynamic template fields in gridview in that case after when I click on button(i.e) after postback control appear with previous values appended with dot with current values.for example if a Textbox has values ="123" and if change to "22" then after postback TextBox will have values "123.22".I want only new value 22 not like "123.22"

Comment: You will have to show more code of where you think the problem is. I would show the markup of the gridview and the markup on the button click. I think the problem is with your button click event itself, but no way of telling without seeing the code.